# highchart.js is not working. error 13

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

This is the image of the error:

[image]

This error 13 is always showing up. I just cannot find the reason why `highchart.js` is not working. Can anyone help me to fix this one? Thanks

```
<?php 
    $q = $this->db->query("select * from scli_tbl_services");

    foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
       $data[] = $row->service_id;
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart_sample'
        },
        series: [{
            data: [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>],
            pointStart: 0,
            pointInterval: 10
        }]
    });
</script>

<span id="chart_sample" class="chart_sample"></span>
```

This is my code that I'm about to run. So I don't know if my code also is working fine.

Comment: The error points to a page describing the error, have you looked at it?

Comment: @uvi have to try  data: [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>], instead of Jsonencode format of data.

Comment: @timenomad i tried looking at the error, and tried to run it in my application but it is still producing the same error :)

Comment: @Elangovan, it is still producing the same error, with this error the graph is not showing :(

Comment: @uvi Print ur php array

Comment: @Elangovan tried printing it and it works fine.. but in my highcharts, it has no result '

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/errors/13 Here you can read about your error. You have some mistakes in defining your div. Do you have div with id = 'chart_sample'?

Answer (score -1):

**HighChart.Js Solution :**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>

<?php
$newArray = array(
    "Valvo" => Array(10,15,20),
    "ACBUS" => Array(25,30,15),
    "SchoolBus" => Array(25,30,15),
    "MiniBus" => Array(25,30,15),
    "CityBus" => Array(25,30,15)
);

$json_array_form = array();
$data = '';
foreach ($newArray as $key => $value){
   $json_array_form['name'] = $key;
   $json_array_form['data'] = $value;
   $data    .= json_encode($json_array_form).',';
}
$data = substr($data, 0, -1);
?>
```

**//HighChart Js functionality start**

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [<?php echo $data;?>],
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried running this on a new page, its working, but when i will load this in my application, error 13 is appearing.. i think its about the loading of the highchart.js its not working because of an error.

Comment: @uvi actually i guess, u r forming the highchart series object is wrong.